# Buffering system logs - Raspberry Pi4

Tags: logging, raspberry-pi4

I am forwarding specific logs to a remote syslog server (Graylog) which is on the public internet.
To avoid loosing important logs if the connection is down, I am trying to buffer the logs and then send them as soon as the connection is re-established.
This is the script I am using:

```
*.err;*.crit;*.alert;*.emerg;auth.warning;authpriv.warning;auth.info action(
  type="omfwd"
  target="123.123.123.123"
  port="62300"
  protocol="tcp"
  queue.type="LinkedList"
  queue.filename="buffered_logs_all"
  queue.saveonshutdown="on"
  action.resumeRetryCount="-1"
)
```

but, to start I am experiencing the following error:

> error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/custom_rsyslog.conf, on or before line 11: queue directory '/var/spool/rsyslog' and file name prefix 'buffered_logs_all' already used. This is not possible. Please make it unique.

I have checked and the 'buffered_logs_all' is unique. I am not sure about what else to check to make this working. I will appreciate some help. Thanks